ArcPro Model Spatial Join failing unless I change the output name of feature class
I am creating a model in ArcPro modelbuilder. The model runs two spatial joins. The second one always runs without issue. The first one, which joins a xy point layer to the same shapefile as the 2nd join, will fail unless I change the name of the output feature class. It will not work if I run the model, then delete the output feature class and run it again. IT will only work if I am creating a brand new, never before created feature class with the output from the Spatial join. what the heck am I doing wrong?
